# How to create an immutable Java Object from a Mongo datasource

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm looking to create immutable Java objects directly from a Mongo collection, for example:

```
public final class Sample {

    private final String description;
    private final Integer min;
    private final Integer max;

    public Sample(String description, Integer min, Integer max) {
        this.description = description;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public Integer getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public Integer getMax() {
        return max;
    }
}
```

I've been using the `PojoCodecProvider` to persist the objects, which works well.  However I obviously can't use this for loading the object back, since there is no no-arg constructor:

```
//Doesn't work
MongoCollection<Sample> samples = db.getCollection("samples", Sample.class);
```

Is there a way to do this without extracting all the attributes from the `Document` and calling the constructor myself?  There are going to be lots of these types of object and some will be quite large, if there's a convenient way to do this it would be a great help!

Many thanks.

Comment: nop, you sealed the Sample class so nobody can use the default constructor, you need to iterate then over the MongoCollection and insert one by one in your own collection new Inst. of Sample

Comment: The real good question is why you want to do something like this?

Comment: @akortex91 There are lots of benefits from having an immutable domain model in the service tier: thread safety, caching, protection against `NullPointerExceptions` and many more.

Comment: Yeah I am well aware of those but then again what is your specific use case. Sometimes going the extra mile to implement a design pattern may not be the best case.

Comment: @akortex91 I completely agree, that's one of the reasons I asked the question.  If the inconvenience outweighs the benefits then I'll re-assess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add BSON annotations to your class as stated in mongoDB documentation:

https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.5/bson/pojos/#supporting-pojos-without-no-args-constructors

```java
@BsonDiscriminator
public final class Sample {

    private final String description;
    private final Integer min;
    private final Integer max;

    @BsonCreator
    public Sample(@BsonProperty("description") String description, @BsonProperty("min") Integer min, @BsonProperty("max") Integer max) {
        this.description = description;
        this.min = min;
        this.max = max;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public Integer getMin() {
        return min;
    }

    public Integer getMax() {
        return max;
    }
}
```